# Up-sell: adding a description to the product link

Tags: up-sells, cross-sells, product-linking

I have three products: The first one is a main product which has the second one as up-selling product. They pretty much fit together because they are related somehow (for example a MP3-Player and some headphones).

Now there is a third product, which I also would like to add as a up-selling product, for example a special waterproofed bag which isn't really related to the other two products. Though, you could use that product for the MP3-Player to keep it dry during sports. I would like to add that as a description especially for this relation. Like a "reason" why that product is related to the other one.

Is there any kind of extension or even a way to do that with Magento in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done this or know of an extension that does it, but it certainly looks possible after some quick test. There is a table called `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar` that doesn't seem to be used (correct me if I'm wrong). The varchar column `value` here is perfect for storing a short description of the link.

You can utilize this table to store the "reason" for each of the upsell you're creating. You'll need to create the adminthml interface to store that data when you save upsell products.

Then in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell`, you'll need to `LEFT JOIN` the collection with `atalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`, so that you can have the `value` column available.

The solution to your question spans a broad range of extension-building, all of which can be found on the Internet. Let me know if the flow is not clear. For specific questions, I suggest you make separate posts.

Comment: Well the varchar could be used for that (though I would rather take a _text but there is none on the standard). But besides that, I would be interested, why there is a catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar. For what its used?

Comment: I don't think it's used for anything. You can create `catalog_product_link_attribute_text` if you'd like to use a text field in the `value` column if you need more than 255 characters.